# What background application call xxx-searcher.com URLs without opening any browser?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I'm currently running Norton 360 in Windows 7.

I'm wondering what background application calls the following **xxx-searcher.com** URLs without me opening any browser.

[image]

I look at in **Program and Features**, **services.msc** as well as **msconfig**, but *as far as I know* I could not find any suspicious program or service.

Comment: not any of mine, as far as I can tell. What unusual programs are you running?

Comment: definitely sounds like malware

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does it say under the "Process" column (not visible in the screenshot, it is further to the right)? You could also try a second-opinion scanner such as [Malwarebytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org), if the problem is malware-related.

Comment: Malwarebytes detects **Trojan.MSIL.ECR - c:\windows\System32\alcfum.dll** which attachs to **svchost.exe**. Thank you for your help!